# How to call a function with a delay

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function, which animates a series of bars:

```
function fluctuate(bar) {
  var height = Math.floor(Math.random() * 30) + 5;
    //Animate the equalizer bar repeatedly
    bar.animate({
      height: height
    }, 250, function() {
      fluctuate($(this));
    });
  }

  $(".bar").each(function(i) {
    fluctuate($(this));
  });
```

I want this to play each time a div class (".play") is clicked. How can I enabled this, and limit the animation to 3 seconds, before stopping?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "limit"? I can't figure out what you're trying to do.

Comment: I don't think you've given us enough code, please give us HTML at least.  Also, look into `setTimeout()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run the animation for three seconds only, count the number of times it has been running, and multiple with the animation speed to get the total sum of the animations length :

```
function fluctuate(bar) {
  var height = Math.floor(Math.random() * 30) + 5;
  bar.animate({
      height: height
  }, 250, function() {
      var times = $(this).data('times') || 0;
      if (times <= 12) {
          $(this).data('times', ++times);
          fluctuate($(this));
      }else{
          $(this).data('times', 0);
      }
  });
}

$(".bar").each(function(i) {
    fluctuate($(this));
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/bWR98/)

And a nicer version as a plugin with parameters:

```
$.fn.fluctuate = function(speed, duration) {
    return this.each(function() {
        var self = this,
            times = Math.round(duration / speed),
            iteration = 0;

        (function ani() {
            var height = Math.floor(Math.random() * 30) + 5;
            $(self).animate({ height: height }, speed, function() {
                if (iteration <= times) {
                  iteration++;
                  ani();
                }
            });
        })();
    });
}

$('#test').on('click', function() {
    $(".bar").fluctuate(250, 3000);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/bWR98/1/)

Comment: Perfect answer, thanks. If I wanted to extend this, how would I add a delay to then repeat the function (i.e. animate twice, or more)?

Comment: You could use an interval, or create a callback, here's a quick example where I altered the plugin to use a callback, and using jQuery methods we can add a delay and then call it again -> http://jsfiddle.net/bWR98/2/

Comment: Great, so if I want to loop it indefinitely [cycle][pause][cycle]..etc, I just remove the else statement? That doesn't seem to work.